# How to create complex UI in react native?

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I've read many article about react native interface, but still i'm so bad about `front-end`, so everytime I try to create UI, i've a problem to archieve it,

My current interface look weird :

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

current code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

class MyPatient extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'green', borderRadius: 10, margin:5, height:100}}>
        <View style={{
          backgroundColor:'white',
          marginLeft:15,
          borderRadius:10,
          height:100,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          }}>
          <View style={{borderColor:'red', borderWidth:2, width:50, height: 100}}>
          <Image 
            style={{width:50, height:50, borderRadius:200, }}
            source={{uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg'}}/>
          </View>
          <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row',}}>
            <Text>Asdasdadasdasdsada</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>qweqwqeweqeweqeqwex</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MyPatient;
```

anyone can help me how to archieve my result please?

Comment: @Downvoter, Funny to see Downvoter acting without comment

Comment: I've added an answer that should give you a start. @ me if you get stuck again!

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `flexDirection` to `'row'` in the **white** `<View>`, the one that contains *both* views you want placed row-wise to each other. That should give you a start. Your style should look like:

```
{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    marginLeft:15,
    borderRadius:10,
    height:100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
}
```

You could also set the `alignItems` property of your `<View>` that surrounds the image to `'center'` so that the image is vertically centered in that view.

Comment: good started point to let me archieve my goal,